# join words by following index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset split by words for my Named Entity Recognition. I would like to ensemble some of the words together instead of having it split by words when it should not be.

Example of dataset:

```
print(df[:5])
ID  Word     Start_Idx   End_Idx
1   I          1            2
2   live       4            8
3   in         10           12
4   New        14           17
5   York       18           22
```

As you can see New York is split in two, but the index is only separated by 1, while the other word indexes are separated by 2 (or more).

How can I write a code, that iterates through the End_Idx and Start_Idx and looks for words separated by 1, and then puts them together, so I instead can print a dataframe like:

```
print(df[:5])
ID  Word     Start_Idx   End_Idx
1   I          1            2
2   live       4            8
3   in         10           12
4   New York   14           22
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Iterating? Determining if index separation is one? Putting two words together when you find indices separted by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the End_Idx column, compare it with the Start_Idx and then use a groupby as show below.

```
df = df.groupby(((df["Start_Idx"]  - df["End_Idx"].shift(1)) > 1).cumsum()).agg({'ID': min, 'Word': ' '.join, 'Start_Idx': min, 'End_Idx': max})
```

Output:

```
   ID      Word  Start_Idx  End_Idx
0   1         I          1        2
1   2      live          4        8
2   3        in         10       12
3   4  New York         14       22
```

Comment: Amazing, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thak you very much! :D